# Python lightweight ready many write seldom shared data between processes?

Tags: python

I have a rather unique problem at the moment: Several python processes on a single windows machine are spawned and are assigned jobs, which can take up to a few minutes to complete.
The job assigned to each process is unique - usually described through a uuid.

At any time, a user can issue a kill signal for a specific job - which then should be stopped, mostly to conserve a scarce resource which each job consumes.

I expect the kill signal to be quite rare, but each job will frequently ask "can I proceed with this id?".

Another solution of ours uses a mqsql table with ids to solve this problem, but this is quite slow and I would like to find a faster solution?

I know mmaps and could probably use them, but I have to take a lock while writing a stale id - does anybody know a locking mechanism I can use?

Most ideally I would like to avoid rolling my own solution, so is there some prexisting package? (redis etc. are out, mostly due to configuration issues on the machines).

Comment: It sounds like you are essentially implementing your own task scheduling system. Maybe instead look into a python distributed compute and task scheduling package: such as Dask, Disco, Airflow, Luigi, Celery. This doesn't answer your question but just wanted to mention it in this context.

Comment: I am tackling a similar problem, here is a video on Celery, which answered a lot of my questions. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3cyq5DHjymw. In short, instead of a database, which - as you point out - is slow, RabbitMQ is the best solution for a broker to handle your inter-process communication.

Comment: @AlexGRice Not it's not that sophisticated - more like some processes spun up by FastGCI, which can run up to 10 minutes.
The architecture is not optimal and I would love to switch to something like celery but unfortunately, it's not in the budget.

Comment: @postoronnim I agree - unfortunately, it's too expensive for the business right now, so I'm stuck with something which I can install to python site-packages.

Comment: @Christian Wait a minute, what's expensive? Celery, RabbitMQ are free.

Comment: @postoronnim the time required to integrate celery / rabbitmq in our technology stack is too expensive.Especially since the product needs to have a good installer, since it'S sold as a product. So adding something like celery costs a lot of man hours, especially on the installer.